# Format JSF phone number

Tags: jsf

I am storing a phone number as a string in our database. It would be stored like "1234567890".
I want to display that to the user and format it like (12) 3456-7890
How can I do this with JSF 2.0? 
I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
<h:outputText value="1234567890">
<f:convertNumber pattern="(##) ####-####"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<f:convertNumber>` uses [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) under the covers and this isn't designed with phone numbers in mind.

You'd need to create a custom `Converter` and do the desired job in `getAsString()` implementation using the usual `String` methods such as `substring()` and friends.

```
@FacesConverter("phoneConverter")
public class PhoneConverter implements Converter{

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) {
        String phoneNumber = (String) modelValue;
        StringBuilder formattedPhoneNumber = new StringBuilder();

        // ...

        return formattedPhoneNumber.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        // Conversion is not necessary for now. However, if you ever intend to use 
        // it on input components, you probably want to implement it here.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet");
    }

}
```

Use it as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="1234567890" converter="phoneConverter" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As BalusC answered, you need a converter to do so. I would suggest the following though: instead of writing your own formatting logic, use a library like [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). This will do all the hard work for you. Best practice here would be storing the phone number in your model in [E.164 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164).